# Java: Set -Xms same to -XX:PermSize or -XX:MaxPermSize?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

In Java I have seen that some people set `-Xms` same as `-XX:PermSize` while some others set `-Xms` same as `-XX:MaxPermSize`

Which approach makes sense and why?

Thanks

Comment: Neither. Are you sure that they weren't setting `-Xms` the same as `-Xmx`?

Comment: No. Actually I have never seen in any project `-Xms` set same as `-Xmx`.

Comment: Well, setting minimum and maximum to the same size at least makes sense (see [this](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.outOfMemory#settingHeapSize) for more info). Setting minimum size to match permgen size makes no sense at all, and indicates that whoever is doing it doesn't really understand heap settings.

Answer (score 0):

-Xmx specifies the maximum memory allocation  for a Java Virtual Machine (JVM), while Xms specifies the initial memory/minimum memory allocation.
Example
java -Xmx21024m -Xms128m

In this case JVM will be started with 128MB of Memory and it can go upto 1025MB

Regarding -XX:PermSize specifies the initial size for the Permanent Generation space within your memory provided for JVM, whereas -XX:MaxPermSize is the maximum Permanent Generation that JVM can allocated

These options are used for fine tuning your JVM for specific applications